# How to replace text in a field for a dataset based on a condition- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to convert error messages held in a database table to user-friendly messages in a report.

I want to be able to replace the value in a field based on the literal text within another field.

The current query returns a dataset with three columns `FileName`, `FileContent`, `CurrentDate`:

```
SELECT 
    Left(Filename,Len(Filename)-16) as 'FileName',
    FileContent,
    Right(left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 8), 8) as 'CurrentDate'
FROM ErrorLogs 
WHERE 
     FileContent like '%Error%'
     AND Right(left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 8), 8) = 
             Replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102), '.', '')
ORDER BY 
    filename asc
```

For example if the file name is `ExportFile`, I want `FileContent` to read `There was an error with the export file` and if the file name is `ImportFile` I want `FileContent` to read accordingly.

Thank you in advance for your response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need temp tables to do this.

```
SELECT 
    Left(Filename,Len(Filename)-16) as 'FileName',
    FileContent = CASE 
         WHEN Left(Filename,Len(Filename)-16) = 'ABC' THEN 'File is FUBAR'
         WHEN Left(Filename,Len(Filename)-16) = 'XYZ' THEN 'File is hosed'
         ELSE 'File is good!'
    END,
    Right(left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 8), 8) as 'CurrentDate'
FROM ErrorLogs 
WHERE 
     FileContent like '%Error%'
     AND Right(left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 8), 8) = 
             Replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102), '.', '')
ORDER BY 
    filename asc
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of temporary variable is due to the reason that for update statement no need to go back to database again for join.

```
create table #temp
(
 FileName varchar(15),
 FileContent varchar(1000),
 CurrentDate varchar(50),
)
Insert into #temp
SELECT Left(Filename,Len(Filename)-16) as 'FileName',FileContent ,
Right(left(Filename,Len(Filename)-8),8) as 'CurrentDate'
FROM ErrorLogs 
WHERE FileContent like '%Error%'
AND Right(left(Filename,Len(Filename)-8),8) = 
Replace(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),102),'.','')
ORDER BY filename asc

Update #temp
Set FileContent = CASE
    WHEN FileName = 'ExportFile' THEN 'There was an error with the export file'
    WHEN FileName = 'ImportFile' THEN 'There was an error with the import file'
    ELSE FileContent
  END
Select * from #temp
Drop table #temp
```